# How to display the view generated by the controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a difficulty displaying the view I created. I am studying laravel now and I found this useful article how to create a simple CRUD.

http://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers

But I am stuck at displaying the first layout using the routes. Here's my code so far.

**routes.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::resource('nerd','NerdController');
```

**Nerd.php (model)**

```
<?php

    class Nerd extends Eloquent
    {





    }

?>
```

**NerdController.php (controller)**

```
<?php

class NerdController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        //get all nerds
        $nerds = Nerd::all();

        //load the view
        return View::make('nerds.index')-
            >with('nerds', $nerds);

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('nerds.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

**database setting**

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'laravel_forums',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

**index.blade.php (view)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Look! I'm CRUDding</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ URL::to('nerds') }}">Nerd Alert</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="{{ URL::to('nerds') }}">View All Nerds</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ URL::to('nerds/create') }}">Create a Nerd</a>
    </ul>
</nav>

<h1>All the Nerds</h1>

<!-- will be used to show any messages -->
@if (Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
@endif

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Nerd Level</td>
            <td>Actions</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($nerds as $key => $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $value->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->nerd_level }}</td>

            <!-- we will also add show, edit, and delete buttons -->
            <td>

                <!-- delete the nerd (uses the destroy method DESTROY /nerds/{id} -->
                <!-- we will add this later since its a little more complicated than the other two buttons -->

                <!-- show the nerd (uses the show method found at GET /nerds/{id} -->
                <a class="btn btn-small btn-success" href="{{ URL::to('nerds/' . $value->id) }}">Show this Nerd</a>

                <!-- edit this nerd (uses the edit method found at GET /nerds/{id}/edit -->
                <a class="btn btn-small btn-info" href="{{ URL::to('nerds/' . $value->id . '/edit') }}">Edit this Nerd</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to view the index using this path

```
http://mylocalhost/testsite/nerds
```

I got

```
Not Found

The requested URL /testsite/nerds was not found on this server.
```

That's all guys. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming that app root URL is `http://website.loc/testsite/` the solution is:*

**a:** eighter access this URL thru web browser
`http://mylocalhost/testsite/nerd`

**b:**

```
// or change this
Route::resource('nerd', ...);
// to this
Route::resource('nerds', ...)
```

Simply you told Laravel to catch `/nerd` in URL but access `/nerds` instead. I am sure you got it now :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution sir. I will try it now and hoping that it works. So that I can start studying it again.